# Resize a PHP GD-generated image in PHP and display it

Tags: php, image, resize, gd, image-resizing

I am making an avatar script from scratch and am having some problems. I got transparency working, and multi-image support for heads, bodies, shirts, etc.

Anyhow, I want to be able to generate specific sizes of the avatar within the PHP script. At this time, I have the variable `$baseImage`, which is an image generated using the GD script below:

```
$baseImage = imagecreatefrompng($startAsset);
imagealphablending($baseImage, true);
imagesavealpha($baseImage, true);

... combine all images into $base here

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($baseImage);
```

The size of the image this generates is `350x550 (pixels)` and I want to be able to get a smaller size.

I've done research but cannot find a working solution. What built-in PHP GD functions can resize this, **retain transparency**, and keep the great quality/colors?

Comment: In dumber terms, I want to turn $baseImage into a smaller exact copy of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the size of an image resource directly. Instead, you need to create a new image of the desired size and use [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled) to copy from the fullsize image to the resized one.

Comment: I cannot seem to keep quality when using this method. See: https://www.vortaxia.com/avatar/admin.png